# Given square pyramid, find all skew lines with line AB

Tags: geometry, 3d

Given square pyramid $ABCDE$, find all skew lines with line AB.
Here is drawing:

[image]

It's kind of obvious for me that those lines are $DE$ and $CE$, however I don't know how to prove it.
Note: I can't use analytic geometry.